# Android Studio XML file Ctrl + Alt + L

Tags: android, android-studio

I use Ctrl + Alt + L format XML file in Android Studio,
i want it like this style just like imgae 1 ,but it's always like image 2, how can i do?
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 6):

Go to Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML -> Android -> Check Include Name Space declaration -> Apply

**Ensure settings are set as follows:**

[image: Intendataion]

Go to your XML and `Ctrl + Alt + L`